# Updating a standard field label on a standard object

Tags: force.com

**Goal:**

I'm trying to update the field "solution title" (api name: SolutionName) on the solution object.

**Problem:**

I did:  Your Name | Setup | Customize | Tab Names and Labels | Rename Tabs and Labels. and renamed it to new_label. The new_label is not being applied to the object though. When I repeat my steps, I see that the new_label in the Rename Tabs and Labels is applied, and on views and on page layouts **BUT NOT on the sObject!**

is there a delay on the field label change? Should I have done something else instead? I followed the instructions @ http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_rename.htm

HALP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just referring to the actual setup?

From the [same documentation you referenced](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_rename.htm):

> You can change the display labels of tabs, objects, fields, and other
>   related user interface labels so they better reflect your
>   organization's business requirements. When you rename a label, such as
>   changing the “Accounts” label to “Companies,” the new label appears on
>   all user pages, in Connect for Outlook, and in Connect Offline. **With
>   rare exception, all pages in the Setup area use the default, original
>   labels.**

This is most likely something that doesn't get reflected on that page. Also, I would read up on [these considerations](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_rename_considerations.htm) when doing the renaming. In fact, from that documentation:

> - Most standard tabs and objects can be renamed but not all. For example, the Forecasts tab is not available for renaming. Click Your
>     Name | Setup | Customize | Tab Names and Labels | Rename Tabs and
>     Labels to view a list of the tabs and objects you can rename.
> - **The renamed labels display on all user pages in Salesforce including Personal Setup. However, all pages in the Setup area use the
>     default, original labels.**